# Magento 2: How to call helper function in Controller

Tags: magento-2.1, helper

How to call helper function in controller:-

I have use below code:-

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $helperData;

    public function __construct(
         ....
        \{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data $helperData,
        ....
    ) {
        ....
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
        ....
    }       

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->helperData-><functionName>();
        return;     
    }
}
```

this code give me error as below:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to {Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\Callforprice\Index::__construct() must be an instance of {Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data, none given, called in
```

Comment: What is issue when you are above code?

Comment: Provide your issue with your question.

Comment: after injection has been completed please use di:compile and clear cache and full page cache

Comment: Clear `var/generation` folder

Comment: execute php bin/magento setup:update

Answer (score 4):

Code is correct. This happened to me many times. I have cleared `/var/generation` directory when altering constructor parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Clearing generation + cache will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code..

```
 class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
  {

protected $helperData;

public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data $helperData

) {

    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    parent::__construct($context, $helperData);

}

public function execute()
{
    $this->helperData-><functionName>();
    return;     
}
}
```

Then, Clear Cache and try it, let me know if you have issue...

Comment: Sorry during the draft my question I have forget  to add the the construct and function into class, So i have updated my question, thanks for your answer anyway, good observation :)

Comment: @PurushotamSharma Post your full Constructor

Comment: this is all that I used in my controller file

Comment: With In this class `{Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\Callforprice\Index` You are passing  multiple arguments in ` parent::__construct($context, $second, $thrid);`  If `second argument needed ` `\{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data` instance, you need to pass  `parent::__construct($context, $helperData ,$second, $thrid);``

Comment: So what is the right code in the above scenario?

Comment: @PurushotamSharma  Pass your `$helperData` in second argument.

Answer (score 0):

These types of errors (`Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to...`) occures when you add more parameters to constructor, it would fix after you run di compile command to regenerate your code in generated directory, run following command and it will fix.

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Wow, Magento 2 is so awkward compared to M1. You have to call 4 commands only for adding a helper. Ridiculous...

Comment: LOL. That's true, but I am used to it now. And I find Magento 2 more better than 1.9 in many ways. If you are new to M2 then I must say you do not judge it now. It least work on 2 or 3 projects first.